# "Password Server: Stopped" on Mac OS Lion Server. Stops with error -1 during startup

Tags: ldap, password, mac-osx-server, opendirectory, osx-lion

Since I've restored the Open Directory from an archive because my Server crashed and the DB was corrupt. The password server does not start anymore.
The log looks like this:

```
Feb 14 2012 21:41:20 156746us    Mac OS X Password Service version 376.1 (pid = 2438) was started at: Tue Feb 14 21:41:20 2012.
Feb 14 2012 21:41:20 156801us    RunAppThread Created
Feb 14 2012 21:41:20 156852us    RunAppThread Started
Feb 14 2012 21:41:20 156879us    Initializing Server Globals ...
Feb 14 2012 21:41:20 163094us    Initializing Networking ...
Feb 14 2012 21:41:20 163196us    Initializing TCP ...
Feb 14 2012 21:41:20 191790us    SASL is using realm "SERVER.HOME.POST-NET.CH"
Feb 14 2012 21:41:20 191847us    Starting Central Thread ...
Feb 14 2012 21:41:20 191860us    Starting other server processes ...
Feb 14 2012 21:41:20 191873us    StartCentralThreads: 1 threads to stop
Feb 14 2012 21:41:20 191905us    Initializing TCP ...
Feb 14 2012 21:41:20 191954us    Starting TCP/IP Listener on ethernet interface, port 106
Feb 14 2012 21:41:20 192012us    Starting TCP/IP Listener on ethernet interface, port 3659
Feb 14 2012 21:41:20 192048us    Starting TCP/IP Listener on interface lo0, port 106
Feb 14 2012 21:41:20 192082us    Starting TCP/IP Listener on interface lo0, port 3659
Feb 14 2012 21:41:20 192117us    StartCentralThreads: Created 4 TCP/IP Connection Listeners
Feb 14 2012 21:41:20 192132us    Starting UNIX domain socket listener /var/run/passwordserver
Feb 14 2012 21:41:20 193034us    CRunAppThread::StartUp: caught error -1.
Feb 14 2012 21:41:20 193056us    ** ERROR: The Server received an error during startup.  See error log for details.
Feb 14 2012 21:41:20 193075us    RunAppThread::StartUp() returned: 4294967295
Feb 14 2012 21:41:20 193107us    Stopping server processes ...
Feb 14 2012 21:41:20 193119us    Stopping Network Processes ...
Feb 14 2012 21:41:20 193131us    Deinitializing networking ...
Feb 14 2012 21:41:20 193149us    Server Processes Stopped ...
Feb 14 2012 21:41:20 193165us    RunAppThread Stopped
Feb 14 2012 21:41:20 193202us    Aborting Password Service.  See error log.
```

The error log repeats the following:

```
Feb 14 2012 21:41:50 409022us    Server received error -1 during startup.
Feb 14 2012 21:41:50 409141us    Aborting Password Service.
```

Anyone an idea what's wrong here and how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue. It wasn't the password service - it was a corrupt ldap database.

http://www.iredmail.org/forum/topic3694-iredmail-support-power-cut-ldap-dont-sta rt.html
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4149695?start=0&tstart=0

Here's what I did.

1. check if this is the problem

   ```
   $ sudo /usr/libexec/slapd -Tt 
   >> bdb_db_open: database "cn=authdata": db_open(/var/db/openldap/authdata/id2entry.bdb) failed: Invalid argument (22).
   ```
2. Stop LDAP on OD Master

   ```
   $ sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.openldap.slapd.plist
   ```
3. Repair Permissions

   ```
   $ diskutil repairPermissions /
   ```
4. backup openldap db

   ```
   $ sudo cp /var/db/openldap/authdata/id2entry.bdb /var/db/openldap/authdata/id2entry.bdb.backup
   ```
5. repair

   ```
   $ sudo db_recover -cv -h /var/db/openldap/openldap-data/
   >> Recovery complete at Thu Jun  6 11:01:35 2013
   >> Maximum transaction ID 8000060e Recovery checkpoint [2][6589846]
   ```
6. run repair again to check

   ```
   $ sudo db_recover -cv -h /var/db/openldap/openldap-data/
   >> Finding last valid log LSN: file: 2 offset 6589938
   >> Recovery starting from [1][28]
   >> Recovery complete at Thu Jun  6 11:02:32 2013
   >> Maximum transaction ID 8000060e Recovery checkpoint [2][6589938]`
   ```
7. double check if things were repaired correctly

   ```
   $ sudo /usr/libexec/slapd -Tt
   >> bdb_monitor_db_open: monitoring disabled; configure monitor database to enable
   ```

   config file testing succeeded
8. restart the service

   ```
   $ sudo launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.openldap.slapd.plist
   ```

Answer (score -1):

I've run into similar issues in the past and typically resolve it by replacing the entire contents of /var/db/openldap from a Time Machine backup.

Make sure to stop ldap first:

sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.openldap.slapd.plist

Then For CYA, copy everything inside /var/db/openldap to the location of your choice. Then delete the three folders inside /var/db/openldap.

Open Time Machine from the /var/db/openldap directory and restore the 3 folders from a known working date/time.

Start ldap:

sudo launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.openldap.slapd.plist

For good measure reboot and everything usually comes back to normal.